# How to hide Material-UI raised button when printing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a button on a web page that triggers a print via javascripts window.print() method. Unfortunately, in the print preview, I can still see the button that triggered the print. Is there a way I can set a property to hide this button after being clicked or hide it when I'm trying to print?

I couldn't find anything useful on the Material-UI site, nor anything on SO. I'm thinking I will have to handle this using CSS, but I'm curious if anyone else has run into this issue and if they found another way to hide a button.

Also - If necessary, I could hide my entire toolbar group, but nothing stands out to me on that documentation either.

Comment: did you try 
`@media print { .btn{dispay:hnone;}
   }`

Comment: I saw this mentioned in a few places, but I have not tried it. I want to accomplish this with javascript or a material-ui attribute, but I will look into this as it seems CSS may be the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `@media print` query in your css to set css for printing

```
@media print
{    
    button
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

This should work. See here I added the print query to the main.css of the material.ui site

[image]

and notice the buttons that would normally show in the "Simple examples" section when I go to print are no longer there

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know of anyway to accomplish the same functionality using only a material-ui attribute on the toolbar group or raised button, or by hiding the button with javscript? I'm starting to get the impression that it's not possible.

Comment: This is a good answer and does work as Steven notes above. It does not accomplish the task via material-ui or javascript, but it appears that this CSS code is the only viable fix at this time.

Thank you Steven, this answer has solved our issue.

Comment: It can be accomplished with a Material UI attribute, please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Placing the content you want to hide within a Box with a displayPrint="none" attribute should do the trick. Example:

```
<Box component="span" displayPrint="none">
    your screen only content (this hides when printing)
</Box>
```

Material UI docs [here](https://material-ui.com/system/display/#display-in-print).

Comment: This one doesn't really work when combined with components like Buttons, you have to apply it co a custom component to wrap the component. If you compose the display styles with a Button, it complains about prop passing.

Comment: @simbolo It does work with the Material UI Buttons and I have not had problems with any other elements. I have not tested it extensively across browsers but it works with Chrome and Edge at least. Check out this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-t3m3n?file=/demo.js